# semantic change in 4.2?

Tags: alloy

My question is whether the semantics of () in the declaration of fields had changed in Alloy 4.2.

I read in "Software Abstractions" that

```
addr: (Book -> Name) -> lone Addr
```

means that the relation addr associates **at most** one address with each address book and name pair but this does not hold when running Alloy 4.2

For instance, for

```
sig Book, Name, Addr  {}
sig AddBX {
  addr : (Book -> Name) -> lone Addr
}

run XRun {
  some B : Book, N : Name, X : AddBX | #X.addr[B][N] = 2
}
```

Alloy 4.2 finds a model instance which has for instance AddBX$2 with

```
Book$1 ->Name$0 ->Addr$0
Book$1 ->Name$0 ->Addr$1
Book$1 ->Name$0 ->Addr$2
```

If I use instead

```
addr : Book -> Name -> lone Addr
```

then no instance for the same run is found. This seems to indicate that in Alloy 4.2 this is how to declare that the relation addr associates **at most** one address with each address book and name pair but I would like to have a confirmation for this.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a bug in v4.2, the correct behavior is what Alloy4.1.10 implements.

I created a snapshot of v4.2 where this problem is fixed, and you can download it here:

http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/downloads/alloy4.2_2013-01-28.jar

Thanks for reporting this bug.